# How to get list of models that is registred in django admin?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin

I want to get list of models that is registered in django admin. And set in settings which models i want to see in Django admin.

That is registred in Django admin like this:

```
@admin.register(m.Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('customer_type', )
    inlines = (CustomerAccountInline, )
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far ?

Answer (score 5):

You can access admin.site._registry

```
from django.contrib import admin

for model, model_admin in admin.site._registry.items():
    print(model)
```

Comment: admin.site._registery is a dict. So you have forgotten .items() in your forloop

Comment: but this is print nothing

Comment: @DmitryRus  Are you sure ?, I have just tested it.

Comment: @DmitryRus not sure what you are doing wrong, but for me it's actually printing my models.

Comment: Yes, i have about 20 models that is registered in admin but this is print nothing

Comment: @DmitryRus Make sure to use admin.site._registry.items() and maybe try another place?

Comment: I used it from django shell

Comment: It should print.

Answer (score 1):

To get your models:

```
import django.apps
django.apps.apps.get_models()
```

Managing your django admin can be done in the admin.py file. More can be read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: How i can check that this models exists in django admin?

Comment: Which model do you mean?

Comment: That is registred in Django admin like this ```@admin.register(m.Customer)
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('customer_type', )
    inlines = (CustomerAccountInline, )
 ```

Comment: Not sure if I get you. But you setup your models in your models.py. After migration you have to register them in your admin.py. After registration you can see them on your admin environment. Did you set up your admin environment?